# Redirecting Specific Subdomain Requests to Main Server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, requirejs

I would like my mobile web app to use the same resources (models, collections, etc.) as my web app, but I am getting 404s. I am using RequireJS (which loads these files), as well as Backbone and jQuery Mobile.

My apps are structured as follows:

```
/
  /js
    /models
    /collections
  /mobile
    /js
```

My subdomain `m.mysite.com` points to `/mobile`. I want all requests for `m.mysite.com/js/models` to redirect to `mysite.com/js/models`, and similarly for `collections` and others.

I have come up with the following code, but it isn't working and I'm still getting 404s:

```
# Redirect all calls to '/models' or '/collections' to regular domain
RewriteRule local\.m\.mysite\.co/js/(models|collections|helpers|objects)/(.*?)$ mysite.co/js/$1/$2 

[L,QSA,R=301]
```

**Note:** I prefixed my local server with `local.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't match against the hostname in a `RewriteRule`, you'll need to use a `RewriteCond` and match against **%{HTTP_HOST}**:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^local\.m\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^js/(models|collections|helpers|objects)/(.*?)$ http://mysite.co/js/$1/$2 [L,QSA,R=301]
```